# Property doesn't exist on type.. error. What is wrong here?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm posting here hoping one of you could help me. I have a very little of programming knowledge and I'm being asked to put together a simple e-commerce website in Angular and ASP.NET Core MVC 3. So the following code is supposed to not log the user out if he/she is logged in but tries to access the admin's page through url. This is a bit of code that my professor told us to use but for some reason it doesn't work for me. He's using an older version of Angular, so for example, where he uses .map(), I have to use .pipe(map()) and where he had response.json().role I did just response.role. My IDE is showing me the following error in the client side login method around response.authenticated and response.role

> Property 'authenticated' (or 'role') does not exist on type 'boolean'.

I suspect the problem is with returning multiple arguments on the client side login method or it's caused by the .pipe(map()). I'm clueless here, to be honest. I'd appreciate any guidance

login:

```
login(): Observable<any> {
    this.authenticated = false;
    return this.repo.login(this.name, this.password).pipe(
        map(response => {           
            if (response.authenticated == 'true') {
                this.authenticated = true;
                this.password = null;
                this.role = response.role;

                if (this.role == 'Administrator') {
                   this.router.navigateByUrl("/admin/overview");
                    this.admin = true;
                }
                else {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl("/");
                }
            }                
            return this.authenticated;
        }),
        catchError(e => {
            this.authenticated = false;
            return of(false);
        })
    );
}
```

server side login:

```
 [HttpPost("/api/account/login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel creds) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && await DoLogin(creds)) {
                IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(creds.Name);

                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Administrator"))

                    return Ok(new { authenticated = "true", role = "Administrator"} );
                else
                    return Ok( new { authenticated = "true", role = "NoAdministrator" }); 
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Comment: Additionally, you're not returning an observable, as you declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear. `response` is not an object to access its members (authenticate).

This returns boolean:

```
this.repo.login(this.name, this.password);
```

Change your condition to:

```
response == 'true'
```

**OR**

According to your backend, the response is an object. Change `this.repo.login` return type to any.